# Linq query for joining many to many tables

Tags: sql, linq, join, lambda, many-to-many

I'm new at LINQ and need your advice.
I have 2 tables like these:

```cs
public class Subjects
{
    public Subjects()
    {
        Classes = new List<Classes>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Classes> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Classes
{
    public Classes()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subjects>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Subjects> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

And Entity Framework create **SubjectClasses**

```cs
public SubjectsMap()
{
    this.HasKey(s => s.Id);

    this.Property(s => s.SubjectName)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    this.ToTable("Subjects");

    this.HasMany(c => c.Classes)
        .WithMany(s => s.Subjects)
        .Map(cs =>
        {
            cs.MapLeftKey("SubjectId");
            cs.MapRightKey("ClassId");
            cs.ToTable("SubjectClasses");
        });
}
```

**Subject---- SubjectClasses ----- Classes**

My Context doesn't have SubjectClasses, so I need to convert the SQL query to Linq or Lambda. But Linqpad doesn't help me or I can't use it. I simply want to take Firstname, SubjectName

```sql
SELECT st.Firstname, s.SubjectName 
FROM SubjectClasses sc
    INNER JOIN Subjects s on s.Id = sc.SubjectId
    INNER JOIN Students st on st.ClassId = sc.ClassId
WHERE sc.ClassId = 3
```

Comment: Like this? `context.Subjects.SelectMany(s => s.Classes, (s, c) => new { s.SubjectName, c.ClassName})`

Comment: and how can I show students.Firstname ?

Answer (score 0):

It's working.

```
               (from st in context.Students
                from s in context.Subjects
                join c in context.Classes
                on new { stuId = st.ClassId } equals new { stuId = c.Id }
                select new ComplexExamResult
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Firstname = st.Firstname,
                    SubjectName = s.SubjectName
                }).Where(c => c.Id == classId).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```